# Entity Framework firebird code first generators

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, firebird

I am learning EF6 and I want to try it with Firebird. The problem is that my generators are not created, only the tables.

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int MajorVersion { get; set; }
    public string PublicKey { get; set; }
    public string privateKey { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProductVersion> ProductVersions { get; set; }
}
```

When executing this code:

```
using (LicenseContext licenseContext = new LicenseContext())
    {
        Product p = new Product { Name = "Test" };
        licenseContext.Products.Add(p);
        licenseContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I get the following error:
`An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

The inner exception reads: `An error was reported while committing a database transaction but it could not be determined whether the transaction succeeded or failed on the database server`

The database still is being created, but with no generators or triggers for Products table. The PrimaryKey is set.

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Is there even an Entity Framework Provider for Firebird?

Comment: Looks like there is ....

Comment: Are you using plain initializers or Migrations?

Comment: I'm using plain: `Database.SetInitializer<LicenseContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<LicenseContext>());`

Comment: Do you have any clue where to start?

Comment: @cincura.net The full error message has something to to with migration, but I have no clue about it, being a novice with EF: `unsuccessful metadata update key size exceeds implementation restriction for index PK __MigrationHistory`

Answer (score -1):

If `ProductId` is a primary key you should to you product instance `p.ProductId = 123;`

Or create a trigger and generator

```
SET TERM;

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER "Product_BI" FOR "Product"
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS 
BEGIN 
    new.id = gen_id("sq_Product",1);
END

SET TERM;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and inform yourself on [writing answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thanks.